# Start-Process another powershell.exe with elevated privileges

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-core

My user account does not have any special privileges. I try to start powershell as user with administrator privileges:

```
Start-Process -Credential $c -FilePath powershell
```

Unfortunately, while indeed another window opens, there must be some strange correlation between both processes: they cannot be practically used.

When I leave out the credential param, both windows appear to be independent.

BTW, I cannot use runas, since it doesn't support PSCredentials and, as far as I can tell, "verb" will not help, as my default user cannot elevate.

Comment: What does "my default user cannot elevate" mean? (Keep in mind that elevation and running with different credentials are two distinct concepts.)

Comment: AFAICT, runas will request more privileges for the current user. My current user cannot do that (he is not granted any additional privileges). So I need to run as a completely different user, because this one can have elevated privileges.

Comment: I just tried (again): "verb" and "credential" appear to be mutually exclusive.

Comment: Argh - I'm sorry. This `Start-Process -FilePath powershell -Credential $c -ArgumentList '-command &{Start-Process powershell}'` will work for me. I swear, I had tried a lot before asking...

Comment: Glad to hear it; please consider posting your solution _as an answer_. Note that there's never a need to enclose a command in `& { ... }` when you use `-Command` (even though the documentation used to suggest the need for that, incorrectly).

Comment: Yes, of course I'll post my solution! Regarding -Command - it seems, not all documented forms work in "Start-Process -ArgumentList". That's a bit strange...